# direct update in MFP verion 6.3 is not working

Tags: iphone, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, maximo-anywhere

I'm getting the below error, while deploying wlapp of Maximo Anywhere in development server.

> Direct update is not working though the wlapp has been deployed.
>
> FWLSE3210W: Environment: iphone of application sampleApp version 7.5.2.0 has been deployed with a different version of the native MobileFirst SDK. Direct updates will no longer be available for existing clients with other versions of the MobileFirst SDK. To continue to use direct updates, increment the app version, publish it to the public app store, deploy to the server, and (optionally) block/notify older versions of the app to enforce customers to upgrade to the new version from the app store.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the exact version of the server and the client ?

Comment: 1) Is the issue specific to Android or iOS or both?
2) Where web resources changed before generating the new wlapp

Comment: wlapp has only  iOS environment. wlapp has code level changes at java script and UI (handlers and app.xml) .Old wlapp has deployed from different computer. If i try to deploy from my/another computer, the above warning appearing and direct update is not working..

Comment: @Srik:Here is the version Server version:6.3.0.00.20150404-1503  client version:6.3.0.00-20151004-0029

Answer (score 0):

Need to manually stop auto upgrading the MFP if you are not using latest SDK. upgradeMFP will upgrade the mobile first SDK . workaround was we created new war and deployed new wlapp, ipa to made direct update to work